# Initialise val in Kotlin from a method in init block

Tags: kotlin

Let's have class as follows:

```
class TestClass()  {
    val isInitialised : Boolean

    init {
        isInitialised = true
    }
}
```

Val `isInitialised` has its initialisation in the init block and the compiler is happy. Once I have more val members I would like to group their initialisation to a method and call the method from the init block, like:

```
class TestClass()  {
    val isInitialised : Boolean

    init {
        setInitValue()
    }
    
    private fun setInitValue() {
        isInitialised = true
    }
}
```

In the second case I receive errors while building:
`Property must be initialized or be abstract` and `Val cannot be reassigned`.

Is there a way to use methods within init block to initialise val members of a class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but you can have multiple init blocks, each corresponding to a method you would use.

Alternately, you could make the properties `lateinit var`, but then

1. it's a `var`, not a `val`;
2. it's easy *not* to initialize it by accident.